# Do retina screens get less bright after a few years?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I've had my MacBook Pro 15" Retina for two years (purchased summer 2014).

The last half-year, I have increasingly found myself wanting to turn up the brightness because I find the screen too dark – only to find that it's already at its maximum.

Do the Retina screens lose brightness over time? I use the device many hours every day.

This is a day-time-only problem, but I can't recall having these problems before. The sun does not have to be very bright for this problem to occur – it can be cloudy. Is my eye-sight getting worse (which could be possible), or do the screens actually degrade over time?